# Is the ratio between two correlated time series significant?

Tags: regression, time-series, normal-distribution, ratio, cauchy-distribution

I have the following two correlated seasonal time series for the same time period:

```
dat$ratio <- dat$ords / dat$reqs
summary(dat)
      reqs              ords             ratio        
 Min.   :   0.00   Min.   : 0.0000   Min.   :0.00000  
 1st Qu.:  27.72   1st Qu.: 0.5606   1st Qu.:0.01862  
 Median :  68.77   Median : 1.5758   Median :0.02308  
 Mean   :  92.68   Mean   : 2.3216   Mean   :    Inf  
 3rd Qu.: 128.72   3rd Qu.: 3.2538   3rd Qu.:0.02764  
 Max.   :2383.61   Max.   :57.8750   Max.   :    Inf  
                                 NA's   :268 

cor(dat, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
           reqs      ords     ratio
reqs  1.0000000 0.8374741 0.2723388
ords  0.8374741 1.0000000 0.5714836
ratio 0.2723388 0.5714836 1.0000000
```

As can be seen by the above correlations, reqs and ords are highly correlated.

Next, here are the histograms of ords, reqs, and the ratio between the two:

[image]

Googling around to learn about distributions of ratios I came across Cauchy distributions, but my stats background is not strong enough to determine whether I have a Gaussian or Cauchy distribution.

Some futher Googling indicates I may have to look at Vector Autoregression.

What further statistical analysis can I perform to understand the relationship between reqs and ords?